How can I secure a shower pipe from the back side?
I have a shower head which is loose and moves back and forth. Fortunately I have access to the back of it and when I looked, the flange on the elbow connector right before it goes into the shower head is just hanging there, simply held by the hole in the drywall! The space to access the pipe is really tight - an air handler is in front of it. I can squeeze to get in there, but can't do anything major. Any suggestions on how to secure this easily?



Use bolts to secure the flange to a block of wood, then screw the block to adjacent framing.
You could also solder a scrap of pipe across the three pipes to hack up a support. This assumes that the other pipes are fairly rigid, but anything will help.

I thought this was impossible until I realised you can tape the nut to the wench (and/or use a flanged nut)  and then reach around to the pipe side with that to connect the bolt (which goes in from the wood side)

Or put the bolt in from the back. There should be plenty of flex in the pipe to pull it away from the drywall far enough.

oh yeah, OP says it's loose.

Thanks for suggestion. This is what I ended up doing. I took a small 2x4 block and glued that to a longer 1x4 which I screwed into the framing. Then took 3 inch screws which was perfect in length to reach thru the wood and secure the flange.

Get 2 pieces of threaded rod that fit through the holes and use 2 nuts to secure each piece to the bracket.
Now get a piece of framing timber and drill holes to accept the rods fix the timber to the studs (or fix cleats to the studs and fix the timber to the cleats) finally secure the back ends of the rods with washers and nuts. (or fill the holes with epoxy glue if you prefer)

if you can't get bolts in there, attach it to a board with construction adhesive, and screw the board to the studs. Then go back and use spray foam around the fitting. Tape the shower arm around the drywall from the other side so it doesn't escape out the hole.

I may have to do something like what you suggest here. Hard to access this as its tucked away and high up. When you say tape the shower arm, do you mean on the side that is shown in the picture? The other side is the tiled shower stall, so I can't do anything on that side easily except the spray foam.

I was  thinking on the other side but this side would be fine too, just don't want it to ooze through to the tile side.
